# How to over come Bitset error

Tags: c++, binary, bitset

if i write,

```
int a=10,b=12;
int sub = b-a;

std::bitset<8*sub> bits(bitMask);
```

it is giving me an error saying

> error C2975: '_Bits' : invalid template argument for 'std::bitset',
>   expected compile-time constant expression

how to over come this error, i  want to initialize bitset at run time, is it possible?
or there any other way to do this?

Comment: What's `sub`? I'm betting it's a variable. Can you provide some of the code that surrounds the `bits` variable?

Comment: You can't initialize a bitset at runtime; that's why it's a template argument, or compile-time **constant**

Comment: @ Schnommus: how to overcome this problem.. are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

Template parameters must be compile-time constants. Think of a template as a code generator: The code has to be generated *before* you start compiling. You cannot use templates "at runtime"!

```
const unsigned int size = 10;
std::bitset<size> b;  // fine, the compiler knows what "size is"

unsigned int n; cin >> n;
std::bitset<n> c;     // doesn't make sense!
```

As a first step you should say `const` as much as possible in your code; it's possible that you actually do have compile-time constants but aren't declaring them as such.

If you really need a data structure with dynamic size, you need to use something else (e.g. a vector of unsigned chars along with a bitwise accessor function).

---

Here's a very simple implementation of a bit set as a vector of chars. I'm not wrapping this in a class, you can do that if that's needed:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> data;

bool getBit(size_t n, const std::vector<unsigned char> & data)
{
  if (data.size() * CHAR_BIT) <= n) return 0;

  return data[n / CHAR_BIT] & (1U << (n % CHAR_BIT));
}

void setBit(size_t n, std::vector<unsigned char> & data)
{
  if (data.size() * CHAR_BIT) <= n) data.resize(n / CHAR_BIT + 1, 0);

  data[n / CHAR_BIT] |= (1U << (n % CHAR_BIT));
}

// Exercise for the reader
void clrBit(size_t n, std::vector<unsigned char> & data);
void tglBit(size_t n, std::vector<unsigned char> & data);
```

Comment: i tried adding const, its not taking at all.. same error what i have posted is appearing

Comment: Well, post some real code. Your above example should work if you make all the numbers constant.

Comment: const int sub =Count-ErrorByte+1; std::bitset<8*sub> bits(bitMask);

Comment: the above code in my comment doesn't work :(

Comment: *Everything* has to be constant, including `Count` and `ErrorByte`!

Comment: i did, " const int byte_count = ByteCount;
   const int error_byte = ErrorByte;
   const int sub = byte_count-error_byte+1;

   std::bitset<8*sub> bits(bitMask);"

Comment: still above code fails... could you please tell me why?

Comment: Hey, it works only if i assign constant number, eg  const int byte_count= 20 but it does't work if it is const int byte_count = ByteCount.

Comment: No no, **everything** has to be const, recursively :-) This includes `ErrorByte` and `ByteCount`. Basically, you cannot do it *because your data isn't determined at compile time*. Think about it: Code generation. Code has to be generated at compile time. Consider one of the alternatives.

Comment: @KerrekSB let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2089/discussion-between-lll-and-kerrek-sb)

Comment: Hi Kerrek, is there any alternative to bitset to handle these sort of run time situations. please let me know if u have any idea

Comment: I already did: use a dynamic structure. Me, I'd go with `std::vector<unsigned char>`, and then access the `n`th bit as the `n%CHAR_BIT`th bit of `v[n/CHAR_BIT]`.

Comment: could you please post your answer.. it will be very helpful.. i need to enumerate binary data like array based on the number of bytes.

Comment: I wrote a bit of a skeleton code for querying and switching on bits. You can make up the code for switching off and toggling from that I guess.

Answer (score 3):

The Standard's anwser to your question is to use `std::vector<bool>`, which is a bit set which can dynamically accomodate its size.

Please keep in mind that `std::vector<bool>` is a **specialization** of `std::vector` which is allowed to store bits in the most memory efficient way. *(This is why it sucks: it doesn't behave like `std::vector<T>` for other `T`s. If you want a real `std::vector` of `bool`, you can't.)*

The interface is kept identical to `std::bitset` *(this also sucks, because generic code using `vector` will break hell if instantiated with `bool`)*, so your existing code shouldn't break.

The `std::vector<bool>` specialization will be deprecated in the next standard. If you are already using C++0x, the correct alternative is `std::dynamic_bitset`. If you are stuck with the current C++ standard, then `std::vector<bool>` is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`boost::dynamic_bitset`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html) if you want a... dynamic bitset (I know, crazy, right?).

```
boost::dynamic_bitset<> bits(8 * sub, bitMask);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can just stick a `const` on there so it's a `constexpr`:

```
const int a=10,b=12;
const int sub = b-a;

std::bitset<8*sub> bits;
```

(From comment) You can't initialize a bitset at runtime; that's why it's a template argument, or compile-time *constant*

An alternative would be to use a `std::vector` of bools which has been wrapped in a class with some custom access functions

Comment: i tried adding const, its not taking at all.. same error what i have posted is appearing

Comment: There must be something that's not a `constexpr` in your code somewhere. The code here compiles fine on my end.

Comment: Basically just a short way of saying 'constant expression'; It's going to be introduced in C++0x as a keyword that guarantees a statement is a constant expression

Comment: `constexpr` is not supported in VC10.

Comment: Which compiler you are using? The above given code (having 'const') compiles fine.

Comment: @LLL: If you don't believe it works, see this link: http://ideone.com/lJQ5z